# fake httpcontext using Moq framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit, moq

I am following the [Scott hanselman's](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx) blog

but here i am getting httpcontext.current as null. Sometime back i do remember that i wrote some code to fake Httpcontext.current. but unfortunately i dont have the code with me.

How can i fake do this???

I am using Nunit.

Comment: Are you trying to mock it with NUnit or Moq?

Comment: I am using Nunit to write the testcase and need to mock the httpcontext using Moq framework.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you would do it with Moq:

```
var url = "~/sample/url";

var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var mockRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
mockHttpContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(mockRequest.Object);
mockRequest.Setup(x => x.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath).Returns(url);
```